# Как прочитать имя компьютера в С++?

Tags: c++

Как прочитать имя компьютера в С++?
Программа проверяет соответствие имени компьютера с константой, и работает при совпадении. Как получить имя компьютера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несложно догадаться, что это делает [`GetComputerNameW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamew) из `Windows.h`.

Comment: Или [gethostname](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) из `unistd.h` в POSIX

Comment: @avp, можно было и ответом.